# Add System-package to Xamarin PCL project

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library

I have multiple `PCL projects` and one `iOS` project in my solution. 
When I click

> `References -> Edit`

References in the `iOS` project, i get a list of multiple packages that i could add, including `e.g. System.Json.` In the `PCL` projects, this list doesn't contain the System-packages. Is it possible to add `System-packages` like `System.Json` to a `PCL` project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *System...* DLL:s are generally intended for a specific platform target, so No, you cannot normally add these to your PCL project.

If you are specifically looking for JSON functionality, you might want to consider using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), which is available for PCL.